# Unable to use conditional(when statement and with_file) for ansible role

Tags: ansible

I want to run ansible role with following condition.

`roles:
   - role: /home/ansible/myrole_1
     when: "'myrole_1' not in  item"
     with_file:
      - "/var/log/play_status.log"`

In /var/log/play_status.log, I have entry for myrole_1. Like:-
cat "/var/log/play_status.log".

myrole_1.

myrole_2

But during execution, I am getting error:-

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
```

msg: |-
    The conditional check ''myrole_1' not in item' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ('myrole_1' not in item): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if 'myrole_1' not in item %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).
    Make sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'AnsibleUndefined' is not iterable

If I am using the same condition for task, then it is working fine.

- debug:
    msg: "I am running..."
   when: "'myrole_1' in item"
   with_file: /var/log/play_status.log

  Is there any limitation for role OR I am doing anything wrong?

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Try, as a task. using the `include_role` module.

Comment: Thanks Jack. It worked.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when the syntax in your example is eventually using `import_roles` behind the scenes.

With `import_roles` (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#id9) the role is always executed and each task inside the role is evaluated against the condition.

Let's assume that I have the following tasks in my_role1:

```
- debug:
    msg: "inside role"
- debug:
    var: item
  with_file:
    - "/var/log/play_status.log"
```

When we call the role like your example does, this is what actually evaluated:

```
- debug:
    msg: "inside role"
  when: "'myrole_1' not in  item"
- debug:
    var: item
  with_file:
    - "/var/log/play_status.log"
  when: "'myrole_1' not in  item"
```

`item` is not defined in the first debug task, hence the error.

to make the playbook execute the tasks inside the role only when the condition is met, do this:

```
tasks:
  - include_role: /home/ansible/myrole_1
    when: "'myrole_1' not in  item"
    with_file:
      - "/var/log/play_status.log"
```